# Uncorrect export data

Tags: yii2

I have two buttons in view

```
<div style="width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;">
    <form method="POST">
        <input id="form-token" type="hidden" name="<?=Yii::$app->request->csrfParam?>"
               value="<?=Yii::$app->request->csrfToken?>"/>
        <br><button type="submit" name="last_month" class='btn btn-primary' style="width:120px;height:50px;display:inline-block;" > Прошлый<br> месяц </button>
        <button type="submit" name="pre_last_month" class='btn btn-primary' style="width:120px;height:50px;display:inline-block;margin-top:0;" > Позапрошлый<br> месяц </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

In controller

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $data = null;

//        $data = order::getTest();
        if(isset($_POST['last_month'])) {
            $data = order::getTest();

        }

        if(isset($_POST['pre_last_month'])) {
            $data = order::getCheckPreLastMonth();

        }

        $dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
            'allModels' => $data,
            'sort' => [
            ],
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 50,
            ],
        ]);

        return $this->render('index',['dataProvider' =>$dataProvider]);
}
```

When I try to export data with `kartik\export\ExportMenu` it exports only name of columns without data. When I uncomment `$data = order::getTest();` it correctly exports data but always exports data from `getTest();` after click on each button.
UPD. when action like this

```
    public function actionIndex()
{
    $data = order::getCheck();

    $dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
        'allModels' => $data,
        'sort' => [
            'attributes' => ['order_customFields_delivery_method']
        ],
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 50,
        ],
    ]);
    return $this->render('index',['dataProvider' =>$dataProvider]);
}
```

all data export correct
after var_dump($_POST) `array(2) { ["_csrf-backend"]=> string(56) "MWhMVmJRRkVdWBwJCyl/A2k3IAQlYQwLSVF/GFFpcA12MS8uBT00DA==" ["last_month"]=> string(0) "" }`

Comment: check for the real content of $_POST  .. try a var_dump($_POST)  .

Comment: @scaisEdge when action like this `public function actionIndex()
    {
        $data = order::getCheck();

        $dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
            'allModels' => $data,
            'sort' => [
                'attributes' => ['order_customFields_delivery_method']
            ],
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 50,
            ],
        ]);
        return $this->render('index',['dataProvider' =>$dataProvider]);
    }` all data export correct

Comment: if you update your question adding a well formatted  code  .. is better  .. please ..

Comment: @scaisEdge sorry..update question

Comment: Seems you have problem with $_POST  ..then  try var_dump($_POST) and add the result to your question please ..

Comment: @scaisEdge add result of var_dump($_POST)

Comment: @scaisEdge hi.any ideas about problem?

Comment: Your var_dump(...) seems correct  .. i see you have a 'last_month' in your $_POST so don't understand why don't perform the proper branch of code .. could you is the $data = null ... try use $data = [];